# row total and make filtered list c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, multiline

I have a datagrid which shows a list of patients. Each patient has a column for total amount and for the amount received. I used a textbox multiline to save this data and I wrote this line to calculate each amount and show it in a textbox.

```
foreach (string line in this.txtBoxTotalAmount.Lines)
{
    decimal.TryParse(line, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out valueDoit);
    totalDoit += valueDoit;
}

this.txtTotalAmount.Text = totalDoit.ToString("");

foreach (string line in this.txtBoxAmountReceived.Lines)
{
    decimal.TryParse(line, NumberStyles.Currency, null, out valueRecu);
    totalRecu += valueRecu;
}

this.txtAmountReceived.Text = totalRecu.ToString("");
```

what I need to know is how I can make a button to filter my `DataGridView` in this form.

- if amount received = total amount   // don't show patient name
- if amount received < total amount   // show patient name in a new datagridview.

The new datagridview will show the filtered patient name. Thank you

Comment: In which context you want to filter the data? Which data exactly? please provice more information and show what you have tried till now.

Comment: let say for exemple total ammount = 320  and received ammount is 40 , 80 , 20 ... with the code i have i can calculate the received ammount and showit in a textbox. i add a line to compare between total ammount and received ammount. this idea is for one client. but i have multiples clients and my goal is to print client who there ammount received < total ammount  in a new datagrid. i don't know how can i start this idea.

Comment: I still cannot understand. You said you want to filter the data, Where the data you want to filter? and in which way you want to filter it? The example you provided does not include any filtering. Where is the data exactly?

Comment: I will filter the list of names of my clients and display only the names of which ammount received < total ammount. and take this filtred list to a new datagrid. thankyou Mohammed i will try to find how can i do it.